# Ios Can i get Upload progress from Graph api Facebook?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app i need to upload a video to the user's facebook wall. I use this code and it works:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error)
 {
     if (error)
     {
         //showing an alert for failure

     }
     else
     {
         //showing an alert for success



     }

 }];
```

I wanna add a progress bar during the upload time... but i can't find anything that works...I have read the documentation also, but i can't find anything... There is a way manage a progress bar for @"me/videos" ?

Comment: No, there is no endpoint for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a FBRequestConnectionDelegate on the FBRequestConnection, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBRequestConnectionDelegate/, and implement the requestConnection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite method.

Your progress should be totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite.

You also need to create the FBRequest and the FBRequestConnection separately if you want to set the delegate, something like:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForUploadVideo:@"some_path"];
FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
[connection addRequest:request completionHandler:YOUR_HANDLER_HERE];
connection.delegate = self;
[connection start];
```

Comment: i have implemented the method requestConnection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite and the delegate in my .h but it never get called... How i can set "delegate=self" in my code above?